# Why does my code freeze when I recurse with ellipses?

Tags: recursion, racket

It does not look like it is recursing infinitely because I have a base case, and each recursion call takes a smaller list `arg1`.

```
#lang racket

(define a '("Hat" "Shoes"))

(define b '("Coat" "Hat"))

(define c '("Shirt" "Pants"))

(define-syntax func
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((func arg1 arg2 ... n)
     (if (or (empty? arg1) (empty? arg2) ...)
         empty
         (if (or (member (first arg1) arg2) ...)
             (cons (string-append n "." (first arg1)) (func (rest arg1) arg2 ... n))
             (cons (first arg1) (func (rest arg1) arg2 ... n))
             )
         )
     )
    )
  )

(func a b c "prefix")
```

Comment: Please don’t use a macro for this; `func` should be a function. This just dramatically increases code size unnecessarily.

Comment: I seem to be having trouble having functions accept ellipses, and replicating what I'm trying to accomplish with this macro. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a macro `func`.

Then you use the macro: `(func a b c "prefix")`.
When a macro is used, the macro expander looks up the definition and matches the use with the input pattern and uses the template to produce the expansion.

Here `(func a b c "prefix")` is matched with `(func arg1 arg2 ... n)`.
So `arg1 = a, arg2 = (b c), and n = "prefix"`.

Now the template is used. Inside the template I spot:

```
 (func (rest arg1) arg2 ... n))
```

Let's fill in:

```
 (func (rest a) b c "prefix"))
```

of course the rest of the template is also filled in.
Now since the output of the macro has a use of `func` the macro expander
now needs to expand the new use: `(func (rest a) b c "prefix"))`.
The output of that expansion will contain `(func (rest (rest a)) b c "prefix"))` (and more). The macro expander now expands that expression and gets `(func (rest (rest (rest a))) b c "prefix"))`.

The problem is not that `func` uses `func`, but that the size of the arguments to `func` doesn't decrease. It shows that one must be careful when writing recursive macros.

Comment: In what ways can I achieve what my code intended? Thank you.

Comment: Can you state the intention in words? Can you show some examples of input and output?

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use a macro for this. Macros should be used for generating code, but there is no need to do that here. Be *especially* wary about using macros that expand to themselves—they will recursively expand! As soegaard has helpfully pointed out, in this case, your macro is infinitely expanding, producing an infinite amount of code. This is obviously very bad.

Remember that macros run at compile-time, not at runtime, so it is impossible for a macro’s expansion to depend on a runtime value. For that reason, your “base case” does not make sense in the context of macros: from the macro’s point of view, there is no point at which it will stop expanding.

What you want is a plain old variadic function. The syntax to do that in Racket/Scheme looks like this:

```
(define (f . args)
  ; do something with args
  )
```

In the above example, `args` will be bound to a list containing all of the arguments provided to `f`. You can use this to implement `func` as a function. If you also want the more declarative pattern matching functionality that `syntax-rules` provides, you should take a look at `match`.